# Rejecting / Resolving a promise from outside its body

Tags: ember.js, promise, cancellation

I have a need to reject a promise from outside its body, to handle the case of the user that wanted to cancel the action.

Here, I need to start several uploads at the same time, by calling #start on every queued uploads.
The class that manages the uploads queue then stores all the promises and uses `Ember.RSVP.all` to handle when all the promises have resolved or one has rejected. This works fine.

Now, I would like to cancel the upload

```
App.Upload = Ember.Object.extend({
  start: function() {
    var self = this;

    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      self.startUpload() // Async upload with jQuery
        .then(
          function(resp) { resolve(resp) },
          function(error) { reject(error) }
        );
    });
  },

  cancel: function() {
    this.get('currentUpload').cancel() // Works, and cancels the upload
    // Would like to reject the promise here
  },

  startUpload: function() {
    return this.set('currentUpload', /* some jqXHR that i build to upload */)
  }
});
```

I have thought of many ways to handle it, but I don't found any method like `myPromise.reject(reason)`.

So what I did, is to store the `reject` function in the `Upload` instance and call it from my `cancel` method, like this :

```
App.Upload = Ember.Object.extend({
  start: function() {
    var self = this;

    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      /* Store it here */
      self.set('rejectUpload', reject); 
      /* ------------- */

      self.startUpload() // Async upload with jQuery
        .then(
          function(resp) { resolve(resp) },
          function(error) { reject(error) }
        );
    });
  },

  cancel: function() {
    this.get('currentUpload').cancel() // Works, and cancels the upload

    /* Reject the promise here */
    var reject;
    if (reject = this.get('rejectUpload')) reject();
    /* ----------------------- */
  },

  startUpload: function() {
    return this.set('currentUpload', /* some jqXHR that i build to upload */)
  }
});
```

This sound a bit dirty to me, and I'd like to know if there was a better way to make this.

Thanks for your time !

Comment: Why are you wrapping `startUpload` with the promise constructor?

Comment: Wait, no - this is wrong logically (what you're doing here), you're counting on the fact promises only resolve once to prevent the side effects and not actually cancelling the upload. I recommend that you use a promise library that supports cancellation like Bluebird.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var deferred = Ember.RSVP.defer();

deferred.resolve("Success!");
deferred.reject("End of the world");
```

To access the promise (for thening etc)

```
deferred.promise.then(function(){
  console.log('all good');
},function(){
  console.log('all bad');
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the time to answer back and thanks for your suggestion. I'll accept it as soon as I've tested it on monday !